# Despite installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, after ejecting CD, unconditionally boots Windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, cd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Win 7, but each time it gets past the (install Ubuntu in Windows 7) option, it just stops and ejects the CD asking me to press the enter key. After this, it just boots back into Windows. And when I try to install with my network connection enabled, I get a (6136) terminated by signal 15 error (NM Dispatcher action caught signal 15 shutting down.) Unallocated space - 70GB on C drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Wubi to install 12.04 LTS on your Windows machine. Here is a Ubuntu link to if specifically for 12.04 LTS.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give that a try. Will I still need to use the same disk I put the Ubuntu.ISO on?